# Power automate dataflow refresh after mail recieved

Tags: email, automation, google-cloud-dataflow, refresh, power-automate

I try to create a new automation. The point is to have dynamical automatical refresh service in case of refreshes fail.

The  source is recieved mail, which contains the name of failed dataflow in subject ( Refresh failed: Your TestDF dataflow couldn’t be refreshed ).

Flow has manual trigger for testing.

[Data automation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1AArJ.png)

After I parsed the DF name from subjec, I put it inside the Refresh a dataflow automate step, but the main problem is that if you push the outcome from Compose 1 ( Parsing ), instead of choosing it from the list in step setting, the automatization did not match the DF name with the DF ID and push the string to the Json, where the IS should be. This will ends with 404.

[Flow refresh settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TbH02.png)

```
{
    "host": {
        "connectionReferenceName": "shared_dataflows",
        "operationId": "RefreshDataflow"
    },
    "parameters": {
        "workspaceType": "Workspace",
        "groupIdForRefreshDataflow": "111111111-2222222-3333-4444-5555555555555",
        **"dataflowIdForRefreshDataflow": "TestDF"** // There should be the dataflow ID

    }
}
```

Can somebody help me with this ? Any idea of what to change ?

The point is to have dynamical automatical refresh service in case of refreshes fail.

Thank you.

Many other ways to create this automation.